# space of all lipschitz maps is a polish metric space

Tags: functional-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

Suppose that $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y )$ are Polish metric spaces. Let $L(X, Y )$ denote the set of all Lipschitz maps from $X$ to $Y$ with the pointwise convergence topology.

Show that $L(X, Y )$ is a polish space.

Hint: Consider $d_L(f, g) = \Sigma_{i ∈ ω} 2^{−(i+1)}d_Y (f(x_i), g(x_j ))$.

I am having trouble showing that this metric is complete. And also to show that $L(X,Y)$ is separable ( I tried to use the fact of both $X$ and $Y$ are Polish and pointwise convergence topology, but it did not work).

Any thoughts or help will be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a typo in the definition of $d_L$?  I think it should probably be $\sum_i 2^{-(i+1)} d_Y(f(x_i), g(x_i))$.

Comment: yes, there is Nate. Thank you for point it out.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the correct definition of $d_L$ is $d_L(f,g) = \sum_i 2^{-(i+1)} d_Y(f(x_i), g(x_i))$.

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L(X,Y)$.  Hints:

- Show that for each $i$, $\{f_n(x_i)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$.  Therefore...
- If $f$ is going to be the limit of $f_n$, this tells you what $f(x_i)$ has to be, for each $i$.
- If $f$ is going to be Lipschitz (in particular, continuous), then what does $f(x)$ have to be for $x$ which are not among the $x_i$?  (Is this well defined?)
- Now you have a candidate $f$ for the limit of $f_n$.  Verify that this function $f$ is Lipschitz.  Finally verify that $f_n \to f$ in the $d_L$ metric.

Comment: Thank you for your hints Nate! The first two steps, I think I could grasp. But I still do not understand how can I define when $f(x)$ when $x$ is not one of the $x_i$.

Comment: Hint: The $x_i$ are supposed to be a countable **dense** subset of $X$.  So given $x$, there is a subsequence $x_{i_k}$ of $x_i$ converging to $x$.  So in terms of $f(x_{i_k})$, what would $f(x)$ have to be?  (To check this is well defined: if you chose a different subsequence, would you get the same thing?)

Comment: thank you again for your time Nate! Then I will need to restrict the metric $d_Y$ to a dense set, say, $D$, in order to show that $d_L$ is complete. Is that right? Therefore, $d_L$ will depend on the choice of this dense set $D$. Can I conclude that $d_L$ is a complete metric, even with this sort of "choice dependence"?